# session conflict because of ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, session

I have a problem, at the beginning of my index it is necessary to start a session (due to the login verification).

The problem is that I use ajax to update a div (this div that through an include leads to a page in php (action.php), which has several things that require a session). As I already started the session in the first "upload", this div has no problem, but from the second, as the upload is only in the div it does not go through the beginning of my site (where I started the session), the problem, the page php (action.php) I gave doesn't work because there is a session.

If I put the session on that php page (action.php), when my index (main page) loads for the first time, it loads its session and loads the session for that include (which generates an error because it cannot start 2 sessions)

Code:

Index

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../verificar_login.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section">
        <div id="pai">
            <?php include "action.php"; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Action.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../class/users.php');
$id_session = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Ajax

```
var time = 1000; // 1s
setInterval(function(){ 
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST', 'action.php');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
        // console.log(ajax.readyState) //estado 4 indica requisição finalizada
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('pai').innerHTML = ajax.responseText /* ajax.responseText -> nele está contido o html requisitado */
            //document.getElementById('loading').remove()
        }

        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status == 404) {
            document.getElementById('pai').innerHTML = 'Tente novamente mais tarde'
            //document.getElementById('loading').remove()
        }
        
    }
    ajax.send();
}, time);
```

Comment: Are you using action.php both as an include in your index page _and_ as the independent target of an AJAX request? If so then that's your design flaw right there. Keep those things separate. If they both need to call the same background code then fine, but don't make the bit which loads the session be included in both situations. Just needs a quick rethink of your code structure.

Comment: If you're including `include('../verificar_login.php');` at the start of the page, then you don't need `session_start();` in index.

Comment: session_state is not just to include, there are also fields on my website that I call session ['example'], which require this.

Comment: in other words, I can't remove this session_start

Comment: Read my first comment again. You can't use action.php in this dual-purpose way. Break the code down further so that index you can re-use code you need without including action.php direct